# Conditionally moving columns

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, conditional-statements, multiple-columns

I have a series of grants I am keeping track of and one of the rows is "Status", which can either be "Active" or "Inactive". When the status changes to "Inactive", I would like that column to be copied to another sheet titled "Inactive". The original can either be deleted or I can create another sheet for active grants called "Active" and have the same process take place for those, whichever is easier.

I tried to modify some [code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26986063/excel-macro-to-copy-specific-columns-conditionally-to-another-worksheet) I found on the internet for similar processes, but I had no luck.

Comment: I tried manipulating code from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26986063/excel-macro-to-copy-specific-columns-conditionally-to-another-worksheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've corrected a bit the code that you linked.

First, take a look at my original data:

[image: before1] [image: before2]

The code (change the values in the first 4 commented lines to what you need):

```
Option Explicit

Sub Move_Inactive_to_Other_Sheet()
    Const sOrigSheet As String = "Sheet1"       'Name of the original sheet
    Const lStatusRow As Long = 2                'the # of row where you have Status in the original sheet
    Const sInactSheet As String = "inactive"    'Name of the sheet where inactive data is put
    Const lInactStartCol As Long = 2            'Column # in the Inactive data sheet where data starts to be put
    Dim lColCount As Long
    Dim c As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim Sh1 As Worksheet, Sh2 As Worksheet
    Set Sh1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sOrigSheet)
    Set Sh2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sInactSheet)

    lColCount = Range(Sh1.Cells(1, 1), Sh1.UsedRange).Rows.Count
    i = lInactStartCol
    For c = 1 To lColCount
        If Sh1.Cells(lStatusRow, c).Value = "inactive" Then
            Sh1.Columns(c).Copy Destination:=Sh2.Columns(i)
            Sh1.Columns(c).EntireColumn.Delete
            c = c - 1
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next
    Sh2.Activate
End Sub
```

The result after the code was run:

[image: after1] [image: after2]